# Динамическое создание кнопок и работа с ними C#

Tags: c#, winforms, события

Короче, суть в чем, я создаю кнопки на динамической форме и хочу чтобы у каждой кнопки было све нажатие или что-нибудь такое, по которому я смогу проверить какая кнопка была нажата и сохранить его, после нажатия другой уже кнопки сравнить их текст если они будут совпадать то обе кнопки убрать с формы.

я делаю так,

```
arr[i].Click += new EventHandler(button_1); //arr это массив кнопок
```

заместо `button_1` нужно сделать например `button_2,button_3` и т.д. кнопок очень много.

Comment: Все кнопки можно подписывать на один и тот же обработчик события. В обработчик приходить параметром `sender`, приводите его к типу `Button` и либо по названию, либо по тегу вы сможете определить от какой кнопки пришло событие.

Comment: а по тегу это как ? Вот например я нажатую кнопку пихаю в массив кнопок,наращиваю значение флага,и так по очереди,и проверяю последнюю с предпоследним (ничего не выходит), потом при попытке оттуда достать и что-либо сделать но пишет System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта." ?

Comment: @Hectordjan - очень интересный рассказ. Лучше покажите код - ссылка "править" под вопросом.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

К примеру у нас есть такой код, который добавляет на нашу форму 10 кнопок:

```
int top = 10;
int left = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Left = left;
    button.Top = top;

    this.Controls.Add(button);
    top += button.Height + 2;
}
```

Как мы можем узнать кнопку? Для этого нужен какой либо идентификатор, возьмем к примеру имя, пусть оно будет `btn{порядковый номер}`. Добавим после строки `button.Top = top;` еще одну строку `button.Name = "btn" + i;`.

Далее, как нам отследить нажатие? Для этого нужно подписаться на событие. Стандартный вариант - `Click` - событие, которое происходит при клике мышью по объекту. Для всех наших кнопок достаточно всего одного обработчика событий! Давайте добавим еще одну строку в свойство кнопки - `button.Click += ButtonOnClick;`.

Хорошо, с генерацией покончили, теперь наш код выглядит так:

```
int top = 10;
int left = 10;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Button button = new Button();
    button.Left = left;
    button.Top = top;
    button.Name = "btn" + i;
    button.Click += ButtonOnClick;

    this.Controls.Add(button);
    top += button.Height + 2;
}
```

Но! Мы не добавили то, что будет выполнятся при нажатие на кнопку, давайте напишем:

```
private void ButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{

}
```

Хорошо, ошибок нет, должно все работать. Но, нужно ведь наделить каким то функционалом наши кнопки... Давайте в `ButtonOnClick` добавим определение нажатой кнопки и ее удаление:

```
var button = (Button)sender;
if (button != null)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Прощай " + button.Name);
    button.Dispose();
}
```

Давайте по порядку:

- var button = (Button)sender; - Событие `Click` выдает нам объект `sender`, который содержит в себе всю информацию о том, кто послал данное событие. Мы знаем, что клик по кнопке производят объекты типа `Button`, значит смело можем привести `sender` к типу `Button` и записать это в переменную.
- `if (button != null)` Тут мы проверяем, все ли у нас хорошо и не равна ли полученная нами кнопка `Null`. Кстати, в новых версиях C# языка все это можно очень грамотно упростить (а именно заменив "шапку" if и первую строку на `if (sender is Button button)`.
- `MessageBox.Show("Прощай " + button.Name);` - Ну, обычный вывод сообщения, нечего сверхъестественного. Единственное, подобную "компоновку" `string` можно очень просто сократить (опять же, новые версии языка, но знать думаю будет полезно), а именно `"Прощай " + button.Name` мы меняем на `$"Прощай {button.Name}"`.
- `button.Dispose();` - Здесь тоже довольно просто, говорим кнопке "пока!", а если быть точнее, то удаляем все занятые ей ресурсы (что приведет к ее удалению с формы).

Чтож, вроде все разложил "по полочкам" как мог, с этой частью думаю трудностей не возникнет. Удачи!

---

> как мне определить не ту кнопку которую сейчас нажали, а ту, которая была нажата до нее.

Создадим где нибудь приватный объект `Button`, который будет хранить информацию о последней нажатой кнопке:

```
private Button ClickedButton;
```

Далее, к примеру, при нажатие 2 раза на кнопку, сделаем так, что бы она удалялась. Для этого перепишем наше событие `ButtonOnClick`:

```
if (sender is Button button)
{
    if (ClickedButton != null)
    {
        if (ClickedButton.Name == button.Name)
        {
            button.Dispose();
        }
    }
    ClickedButton = button;
}
```

- `if (sender is Button button)` - об этом я уже писал выше (приводим `sender` к типу `Button` и если он не `Null`, то выполняем код внутри.
- `if (ClickedButton != null)` - Проверяем, что бы наша "сохраненная" кнопка, не была пустой.
- `if (ClickedButton.Name == button.Name)` - Условие, которое проверяет имена на соответствен. Если они совпадают, то выполняем код внутри.
- `.Dispose();` - Тут тоже все ясно, удаляем объект.
- `ClickedButton = button;` - После всех операций, сохраняем нашу кнопку в заранее созданную переменную, для будущего использования.

Comment: Спасибо вам конечно большое, но это я уже сделал вы покажите лучше как мне определить не ту кнопку которую сейчас нажали, а ту, которая была нажата до нее.

Comment: @Hectordjan Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Hectordjan Вы немного не до конца понимаете концепцию данного ресурса. `stackoverflow` - сообщество людей, которые помогают друг другу и составляют базу знаний, базу ответов так сказать. Я отвечаю не только вам, но и другим людям, которые после вас захотят узнать ответ на подобный вопрос. Ко всему прочему, от куда мне знать то, что у вас уже было написано? Я лишь ответил на то, что имею и как можно подробнее. На будущее советую четче (с вашим кодом) формулировать вопросы, тогда и ответы будут точнее.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вы тоже не до конца понимаете концепцию. Требовать код с автора хорошо именно тем, чтобы потом точнее ответить на вопрос автора, а не на выдуманный вопрос. Откуда мне знать, что у вас уже было написано - так вот брать и просить дописать в вопрос. И не бросаться отвечать. Несколько раз угадаете, а один раз нарвётесь на негатив. У вас хорошие подробные ответы, я вам не один плюс поставил - но в будущем советую более тщательно отбирать вопросы. Нет кода - значит, не больно-то и хотел ответ получить. ;)

Comment: @AK Да, тут вы правы, но... Зачастую я замечаю то, что подобные вопросы остаются и вовсе без ответа, а это как пом мне - вредит самому сайту. По этому я стараюсь все же угадать некоторые аспекты вопроса и дать более развернутый ответ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Вообще, мне этим и нравятся ваши ответы. Видно и знание вопроса и желание объяснять, а не только давать готовый код.

Comment: @AK Ну, когда время есть, почему бы и нет. Стак меня многому научил в плане программирования, внести свой вклад мне не трудно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Не подскажите как на созданной таким способом кнопке поменять цвет и текст?

Comment: @Pashok Ну у вас есть объект `button`, обращайтесь к его свойствам и меняйте что нужно (пример этого - установка имени `button.Name = "btn" + i;`).

Comment: А подскажите как сделать заполнение всей формы кнопками?