# Как создать обработчик для динамических объектов

Tags: c#, winforms

можете подсказать, как написать обработчик для динамических создаваемых объектов (в моем случае по щелчку мыши на форме создаются кнопки) , и например чтобы при нажатии на каждую из них цвет заднего фона менялся ?

Кнопки создаются в этом коде :

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.Button btn = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();

    btn.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(e.X, e.Y);
            
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/795904/220553

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так

```
private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Location = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    btn.Click += Button_Click;
            
    this.Controls.Add(btn);
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button currentBtn = (Button)sender;
    currentBtn.Background = Colors.Green;
}
```

Comment: У меня не работает

Comment: @flyreact сожалею об этом.

Comment: а у вас разве работает ?

Comment: @flyreact чтобы проверить, нужен комп с виндой, а у меня прямо сейчас такого нет, я с телефона код писал. Но и вы держите информацию о том, что именно не работает в секрете, я ж не телепат.

Comment: извините, нашел ошибку , все работает

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: ошибка с моей стороны